# how to eliminate 3 letter words or 4 letter words from a column of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text, nlp, series

I have a dataframe  as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
a = {'b':['category','categorical','cater pillar','coming and going','bat','No Data','calling','cal'],
     'c':['strd1','strd2','strd3', 'strd4','strd5','strd6','strd7', 'strd8']
    }
df11 = pd.DataFrame(a,index=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8'])
```

I wanted to remove words whose length of each value is three.
I expect results to be like:

```
   b                         c
category                   strd1    
categorical                strd2     
cater pillar               strd3
coming and going           strd4      
NaN                        strd5      
No Data                    strd6        
calling                    strd7         
NaN                        strd8
```

Comment: Why was `cal` not removed?

Comment: @Erfan No. check for bat(which is in 5th row in 'b' column ). it was changed to NaN. And Sorry 'cal' hast to be NaN as well. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`series.str.len()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to identify the length of the string in a series and then compare with [`series.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then using [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) you can assign the values of `b` as `np.nan` where the condition matches:

```
df11.loc[df11.b.str.len().eq(3),'b']=np.nan
```

---

```
                   b      c
x1          category  strd1
x2       categorical  strd2
x3      cater pillar  strd3
x4  coming and going  strd4
x5               NaN  strd5
x6           No Data  strd6
x7           calling  strd7
x8               NaN  strd8
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.len` to get the length of each string and then conditionally replace them to`NaN` with `np.where` if the length is equal to 3:

```
df11['b'] = np.where(df11['b'].str.len().eq(3), np.NaN, df11['b'])

                  b      c
0          category  strd1
1       categorical  strd2
2      cater pillar  strd3
3  coming and going  strd4
4               NaN  strd5
5           No Data  strd6
6           calling  strd7
7               NaN  strd8
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check `mask`

```
df11.b.mask(df11.b.str.len()<=3,inplace=True)
df11
Out[16]: 
                   b      c
x1          category  strd1
x2       categorical  strd2
x3      cater pillar  strd3
x4  coming and going  strd4
x5               NaN  strd5
x6           No Data  strd6
x7           calling  strd7
x8               NaN  strd8
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for i, ele in enumerate(df11['b']):
    if len(ele) == 3:
        df11['b'][i] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a where conditional:

```
    df11['b'] = df11['b'].where(df11.b.map(len) != 3, np.nan)
```